# Having trouble reaching my PC (or a PI) from outside LAN

Tags: java, networking, server

so today I've tried to install Citadel Email server on a raspberry pi which went ok but unfortunantly I cannot reach it from outside LAN.

I've tried to pinpoint the problem and use scanner tools that look for open ports like these :https://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/

I've verified that my public IP adress is the same as my domain returns. Which indeed it is.

I've checked port forwarding severel times.

Last but not least I've wrote this java code to have a really simple example:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args){
        try {
            Server server = new Server(8080);

            Client client = new Client(8080);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

package main;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    private boolean stop = false;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(stop == false) {
                    try {
                       Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        outputStream.writeUTF("Hello World!");

                        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        String input = inputStream.readUTF();

                        System.out.println("Client wrote: " + input);

                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable, "server executor");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        this.stop = true;
    }
}


package main;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static final String LOCALHOST = "localhost";
    public static final String KIRAZUKE = "---";
    public static final String PUBLIC_IP_4 = "---";

    public Client(int port)  {
        try{
            doTest(LOCALHOST, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            doTest(KIRAZUKE, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            doTest(PUBLIC_IP_4, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void doTest(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Opening to: " + host);
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeUTF("Hello dear Server ... calling from " + host + " ... over.");

        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String string = inputStream.readUTF();

        System.out.println("Response from server after " + host + " call: " + string);
    }
}
```

So I've replaced the domain name and my public ip with dashes for privacy reasons. But what happens is that when using the localhost connection everything works fine the server prints the text sent by the client and vise versa. While using either the public IP or Domain name it fails due to time out.

What could be reasons that any incoming traffic is blocked altough port forwarding is enabled for the 8080 port (and other ports that I tried) ?

Note: I've also called my ISP, according to them they "don't block anything". Additionally I tried port forwarding port 3389 and tried remote desktop to my pi but that also failed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this a residential ISP contract? What are the first two octets of the address configured on the WAN router (not what a web site tells you, but what is actually configured on the router WAN interface)?

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm Sorry I have to ask. But where best to find it ? As far I'm aware WAN is what sits directly 'above' our LAN. Could I see it via tracert maybe ?

Comment: Just log into the router to look at the addressing assigned in the router. Is this a residential network?

Comment: @RonMaupin 1) yes it is a residential contract. 2) I think there is the problem. Next to "internet, ipv4" it says "DS-Lite-Tunnel, 1&1 Internet". It doesn't display an IP

Comment: OK. A residential contract prohibits running services to the public Internet, and specifically, ISPs have long blocked mail services on residential networks for spam control. Also, you will have difficulty trying to do any such thing with DS-Lite because your WAN is really IPv6 to IPv4 on your site. You need to get a business account, or you need to use a hosted service.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for explaining :) Makes me a bit sad but well :|

Comment: Firstly, there's no point being shy about your public-facing IP address - it's... public. If you're opening ports, they *will* be found by people.
The good news is that what you want to do might well be possible. I've run all sort of services on domestic LANs. Your port-forwarding might not be set up properly. For instance, for it to work, your service cannot be bound to localhost that resolves to the loopback address of 127.0.0.1. It must be listening on your LAN IP address or 0.0.0.0
What does https://www.whatismyip.com/ say your public address is?